# How to process map data from OpenStreetMap with Java?

Tags: preprocessor, openstreetmap, java

I'm developing an Java application which, given a list of street names, must get a route and information about each street name, as the city or cities where each street is located. This is a preprocessing, made in a desktop, for an Android application.

For that I must to process data from some map source like OSM. I need to easily access data from streets and some other points programmatically to select my desired data.

I need to do it with Java. Is there some Java library for this?

Answer (score 2):

The OSM wiki has a [large list of routing software and libraries](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing). Some of them use Java, for example [GraphHopper](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GraphHopper). Also don't forget to take a look at the various [online](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) and [offline](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) routers to get some inspiration.

Comment: What I was looking for is more something to parse an .osm xml file downloaded with JOSM and build an three representing the map structure so that I can browse through the map programmatically and collect the desired data.

Comment: Did you look through the list to verify that none of those libraries does this? Every router/library using a raw XML file instead of a database has to do such processing.

Comment: I was not able to find such thing. So I downloaded the maps using JOSM and started to develop my own solution using JDOM library. I think It will be easier then study and compare each library in details.

Comment: JDOM will fail for large areas as it loads everything into RAM. Have a look into the OSMReader of GraphHopper for an efficient xml or pbf parsing. Also it looks like GraphHopper is exactly what you want: a Java routing engine where preprocessing is done on a server or desktop and you can use it on Android